# Can't run the sample project on spring STS

Tags: eclipse, spring

After installing STS successefuly on Juno, i opened a new MVC project, fixed the errors in the sample STS project by adding all the required spring jars, and now there are 2 problems:

1. I can't get the option: "Run on server" (altough i did set a tomcat's server in the workspace).
2. With every step i make (clean, delete etc') i'm getting the follwing error:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Faceted Project Validation Builder' on project 'First_STS_Project'.
Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants
Errors running builder 'Validation' on project 'First_STS_Project'.
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants

This is not a local problem on my specific workspace, because i getting the same error in my second PC as well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't recommend JUNO since it has many bugs and it also has a bad impact in performance. If you're in Windows, try to use short paths when installing the plugins or selecting the workspace. I have similar issues when working in windows. If I create a workspace in c:/users/Marcelo/Documents/java/workspaces, I always get issues, but whenever I change to "c:/workspaces" directly, works perfectly. Try with Eclipse Indigo instead. Also try to use the latest version of tomcat. If any of the previous recommendations fix the issue, (that could be weird), try to install the STS plugin again but check all the features, maybe a component is missing.